# php cookies are not work with www

Tags: php, cookies

Here is my code
Please tell how its work on www it works without www perfectly

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])) 
    {
        $newvalue=rand(1,10000).time().rand(999,999999);
        setcookie("cookie_name",$newvalue,time()+(86400 * 30),"/","", 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken straight from the [`set_cookie()`](http://php.net/set_cookie) manual:

> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Which means, you need to pass the domain through. Your best bet is to use the following:

```
setcookie("cookie_name",$newvalue,time()+(86400 * 30),"/",".yourdomain.com", 0);
```

<sup>*Notice the leading `.`? That allows it to match all sub-domains, including `www`.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answering i try this also but it will also not create cookie when i open the website with www